# Count total Records of table in C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

I want to count number of record in C#,by using this query got -1 while Delete command is working fine

```
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false);
        var configuration = builder.Build();
        var targetConnectionString= configuration.GetConnectionString("Target");
        DbContext targetContext;
        using (targetContext = _dbContextResolver.Resolve<DbContext>(targetConnectionString, null))
        {
            log.Write("Deleting " + name + " table data");

            var countQuery = $"select count(*) from [dbo].[hospital]";
            var count = targetContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(countQuery);

            targetContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("delete from [dbo].[" + name + "]");
            targetContext.SaveChanges();
            log.Write("--------------------------------------------------------");
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

[ExecuteSqlCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.database.executesqlcommand) returns a "return value", which may be the number of records affected by a DELETE or UPDATE statement.
But this is different from the data resulting from a SELECT-query, which after all may consist of multiple columns and multiple rows (even though this COUNT returns just a single value). So a SELECT will always return a "-1" here.

You will need to use [SqlQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery) to read the data returned by the SELECT.

Comment: I don't really follow the first sentence.

Comment: What Hans means is that ExecuteSqlCommand doesn't return the value extracted by the SELECT statement on the table hospital. It returns the number of rows affected by the command itself. So, you are getting -1 because your command is not intended to affect rows at all.

Comment: Yes it was confusing. Updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

To complete Hans answer where he suggests you to use the SqlQuery method, here is an example of what you could do:

```cs
var count = targetContext.Database.SqlQuery<int>("select count(*) from [dbo].[hospital]").Single();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this multiple ways defined below. (This is example for blog table):

**1st way (using sqlcommand):**

```
string connectionString = Your ConnectionString; (Example:"Data Source=youServerHere;Initial Catalog=YourDataBase;User ID=YourId; Password=YourPassword;")

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlConnection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString);

sqlConnection.Open();

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand sqlCommand = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[blog]");

sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;

int RecordCount = Convert.ToInt32(sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar());
```

**2nd way (using sql query):**

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext())
{
    var blogs = context.blog.SqlQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM dbo.blog").ToList();
}
```

**3rd way (Lambda expression):**

```
int count =  context.blog.ToList().Count();
```

**4th way (Linq Expression):**

```
int count = (from x in context.blog select x).Count();
```